# Spring @RestController

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

I have been trying to extend this Spring/Hibernate/JPA [sample code on Github](https://github.com/Fruzenshtein/spr-data)

While I have got it working OK, I am trying to add a new @RestController to get a JSON listing of all `shop` objects. But my attempts have not been successful.

The existing `@Controller` continues to work just fine, but by new `@RestController` is not recognised, all requests to it result in 404s.

Here is my new, very simple `@RestController`.
It is in the same package as the existing `@Controller` so I expect it to be picked up by the same component scan:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest")
public class ShopRestController {

  @Autowired
  private ShopService shopService;

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public List<Shop> getShops() {
    return shopService.findAll();
  }
}
```

I have made no other changes to the code.

What as I missing?

EDIT:
Sorry forgot to mention that I upgraded the Spring version in pom.xml to 4.2.0.RELEASE

App still works as before except for the new RestController

Comment: Do you keep the pom as it is in the reference but only having changed the spring mvc version?

Comment: Yes, it's all the same except for the version of spring-webmvc

Comment: We need more informations. Check your mapping logs. What do you see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spring [`@RestController`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html) annotation is documented to exist since 4.0 version. Probably you've got some kind of classpath pollution to make the annotation be picked up, but won't be working since the web-mvc version your given link points to is below 4.0.

**Update**

I downloaded the linked project and tested it removing all the Repository and Data related classes in Tomcat 8.0.32. I made it work with this pom file:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>spr-data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spr-data</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spr-data</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>dpr-data</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- slf4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- logback -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- log4jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.log4jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

And this class as the `@RestController`, returning a fake shop String List as json:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest")
public class NavigationController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<String> getShops() {
        return Arrays.asList("Shop1", "Shop2");
    }

}
```

Comment: Glad for it to be handy! As for the dependency problems, if it's a new project, I strongly encourage you to have a look at Spring Boot. It provides many out of the box features, taking care about dependency version compatibilities itself. Definitelly the way to go for new projects.

Answer (score 2):

If you've effectively copied/pasted the POM and just changed the Spring version, this example project does not get Jackson as a dependency - and you need this dependency to serialize/deserialize resources to/from JSON.

Note that as of Spring 4.2, [the minimum required jackson version is 2.6](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Migrating-from-earlier-versions-of-the-Spring-Framework#third-party-dependencies). [Jackson 2.7 will be fully supported in Spring 4.3](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13483).

Answer (score 0):

You miss **'value'** (or **'path'** ) attribute in **@RequestMapping** at method level:
   `@RequestMapping(value = "list", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)` 
Also you must specify response type and include converter in your project. Add **jackson** lib in project pom (see https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Adding the `value = "list"`, will create a new representation to state as `/rest/list`.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub project you mentioned using [Spring 3.2.2.RELEASE](https://github.com/Fruzenshtein/spr-data/blob/master/pom.xml#L51-L55) and to work with `@RestController` you need `Spring version greater than 4` as mentioned in 
[docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html).

```
EDIT: Sorry forgot to mention that I upgraded the Spring version in pom.xml to 4.2.0.RELEASE

App still works as before except for the new RestController
```

To make `@RestController` call work, make sure you are scanning the package in which your class `ShopRestController` class exists, updating the [`WebAppConfig.java`](https://github.com/Fruzenshtein/spr-data/blob/master/src/main/java/com/spr/init/WebAppConfig.java) in sample Github project as follows:

```
@ComponentScan({"com.spr","my.package.second"})
```

And do add below dependency to make `JSON` deserialize your bean:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```